# Does C# BlockingCollection's TryTakeFromAny guarantee sequential checking of BlockingCollection objects?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two blocking collections - one of higheer priority than the other. If I use TryTakeFromAny and specify the higher priority BlockingCollection first, is it guaranteed that the higher priority queue will be looked into first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't documented, so I would say there is no guarantee that it won't change in the future. Relying on it long term is probably not recommended. However, currently, `BlockingCollection<T>.TryTakeFromAny` does a quick check by looping through all the collections by index checking for an item (it checks if Count > 0 and then does `TryTake`). If no items are found it gets an internal wait handle for each collection and passes them to `WaitHandle.WaitAny`. This provides the guarantee:

> This method returns when any handle is signaled. If more than one object becomes signaled during the call, the return value is the array index of the signaled object with the smallest index value of all the signaled objects.

So the current implementation would indeed behave as requested. If two collections get an item simultaneously, the lower index one would get taken.